# outlook 2010 form region cancel button event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vsto, outlook-addin

I am sure this is a really simple question as I am new to VSTO. I have developed an outlook 2010 separate form region which has its own button on the ribbon bar.  It all works fine except I cannot for the life of me work out how to implement a cancel button on the form region. I have spent hours looking for code examples but cant find one.  All I want is for the cancel button to close the form region but i cannot work out how to hook up the button to do this.

Regards
Martin Lines

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.IFormRegion formRegion in Globals.FormRegions)
{
    if (formRegion is FormRegion1)
    {
        FormRegion1 formRegion1 = (FormRegion1)formRegion;
        formRegion1.OutlookFormRegion.Visible = false;
    }
}
```